# I want to make my laptop behaves as server always when i start it, i wants to use apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-3

I want to use apache tomcat and deploy an application I have created in java spring framework.I wants to deploy this application on my tomcat server.

I wants to do that,when i start my laptop and go to my browser and type address "htt://local_host/myproject" then it will automatically open my project without starting a server,and without eclipse's "run on server".

My laptop:Inspiron 15 3rd i5
OS:Windows
Jdk:1.6
spring:3.0
Apache-tomcat: 6/7

Is it possible.?
If yes then how.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install it as a service.

Check this link for more info
http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-start

Here's the essence:

Starting Tomcat Automatically on a Windows Machine
Automatic startup on Windows machines is accomplished by running Tomcat as a Windows Service, a background process that gathers all processes associated with a given application together in one container to be managed by the system. Windows services can be configured to boot automatically at login, and shut down smoothly on logout.

As mentioned in the manual start-up section for Windows distributions, if you utilized the Tomcat EXE installer package to install Tomcat on your Windows machine, you have already installed Tomcat as a service. You can configure the server to start automatically either through the tomcat6w.exe tray program, or by editing the preferences for "Apache Tomcat" in the Services configuration pane, located in the Administrative Tools section of the Windows Control Panel.

You can set the Tomcat service startup option to either "Automatic", if you want the service to start immediately, or "Automatic (Delayed)", which aims for a faster overall system boot by delaying the startup of non-system-critical services until all core components have been loaded.

If you did not use the Windows installer, you can install Tomcat as a service manually. This is outside the scope of this article, but don't worry! We've created a separate step-by-step guide to the Tomcat Service for Windows users in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, take a look at these it shows you have to setup tomcat as a service on windows:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html

and:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Can download tomcat from:

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi